# Unwanted values being added when using complete()

Tags: r, tidyr

Happy New Year, everyone!

I'm having an issue with transforming implicit missing data into explicit missing data. I am summarizing the number of observations of birds at specific survey sites. These sites were surveyed once a month for 12 months. Unfortunately, the collected data only contains information on actual observations of birds rather than also recording that no birds were observed at a site. When I attempt to add in the missing data extra observations are being added to the data.

My solution is to use complete() to fill in the missing data (i.e., the site/month surveys were no birds were observed). I am able to fill in the missing sites with no issues. However, when I try and fill in the missing months that's when the extra observations are being added to sites that did, in fact, record an observation of a bird. Specifically, the additional observations are being added to station 9 for March (1 -> 2 birds) and April (1 -> 2 birds) resulting in 32 total birds observed rather than 30 birds.

Below is an example dataset, and the code that I'm using. I have marked where in the code I am having the issue. I'm brand new to the tidyverse so if you have any general pieces of advice on how to improve my code, I'm all ears. Thanks in advance for your help. I've also included a phot of the correct number of observations just in case. [image: Picture of the Correct Number of Observations]

```
libary(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)

# Create tibble
ea <- tibble(site = c(9,15,9,10,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7),
date = c("3/26/2013","3/26/2013","4/10/2013","4/20/2013","5/31/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","1/9/2014"),
indivs = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1),
within_800 = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))

# Create variable that contains all site names
levels_site <- as.character(1:16)

ea %>%
mutate_at(vars(site), factor) %>% # Convert site into a factor
mutate_at(vars(date), mdy) %>% # convert into a date
mutate(year = year(date))%>% # Pull out year
mutate(month = month(date, label = TRUE)) %>% # Pull out month
mutate(date_ym = make_date(year, month))%>% # Since ym() is not available in Lubridate yet, make a new date that puts all observations from a single month on the same day.
group_by(date_ym, site = site) %>% # Group bysite and month

# Issue here: Removing this code results in the accurate number of observations but only lists the months with an observation.
complete(date_ym = seq(make_date(2013, 3), make_date(2014, 3), by = "month"),fill = list(indivs = 0)) %>% # Add in months were an observations wasn't made

summarise(minutes = sum(indivs)) %>% # Count the number of birds observed
complete(site = levels_site) %>% # Add in the stations were observations weren't made
arrange(fct_relevel(site, levels_site), .by_group = TRUE) %>% # Place in ascending numeric order
pivot_wider(names_from = date_ym, values_from = minutes) %>% # Pivot table
adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col")) # Sum each row and column
```

Comment: @akrun Picture added. I meant to and it slipped my mind. Thanks!

Comment: @akrun Fixed. Stations was an old name. It should work now.

Comment: Can you please check my solution output.  I guess your image includes only selected columns, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue would be in using `complete` with the `group_by` for 'date_ym'.  Also, as part of tidying the code, changed the multiple calls to `mutate_at/mutate` to a single `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)
ea %>% 
      mutate(site = factor(site),
             date = mdy(date),
             year = year(date),
             month = month(date, label = TRUE),
            date_ym = make_date(year, month)) %>%
      group_by(site) %>% 
      complete(date_ym = seq(make_date(2013, 3), make_date(2014, 3),
           by = 'month', fill = list(indivs = 0))) %>% 
      group_by(date_ym, add = TRUE) %>%
      summarise(minutes = sum(indivs)) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      complete(site = levels_site) %>% 
      arrange(factor(site, levels = levels_site)) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = date_ym, values_from = minutes) %>% 
      rename(station = site) %>%
      select(-`NA`) %>%
      adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col")) 
#station 2013-03-01 2013-04-01 2013-05-01 2013-06-01 2013-07-01 2013-08-01 2013-09-01 2013-10-01 2013-11-01
#       1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       2         NA         NA          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       3         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       4         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       5         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       6         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       7         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       8         NA         NA         NA         24         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#       9          1          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      10         NA          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      11         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      12         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      13         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      14         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      15          1         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#      16         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#   Total          2          2          1         24          0          0          0          0          0
# 2013-12-01 2014-01-01 2014-02-01 2014-03-01 Total
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     1
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#        NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#        NA          1         NA         NA     1
#         NA         NA         NA         NA    24
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     2
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     1
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     1
#         NA         NA         NA         NA     0
#          0          1          0          0    30
```

Comment: This is perfect, @akrun! Could you please briefly elaborate on why the error occurred and some of the small pieces of code you added to help solve the issue? Also, thanks for simplifying portions of my code.

Comment: @Matt Thanks.  It is not an error, but using the `grouped` column to do the expansion.  I removed that column from the group by to correct it

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? I have tried to simplify your code a little bit.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Create tibble
ea <- tibble(site = c(9,15,9,10,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7),
             date = c("3/26/2013","3/26/2013","4/10/2013","4/20/2013","5/31/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","6/29/2013","1/9/2014"),
             indivs = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1),
             within_800 = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date) %>% floor_date(unit = "months")) # I have added this part - it turns the characters to date and then transforms them to the first of each month

# Is this what you are tryiing to accomplish?
df <- crossing(site = 1:16, date = seq.Date(from = min(ea$date), to = max(ea$date), by = "months")) %>%
  left_join(ea) %>%
  group_by(site, date) %>%
  summarise(indivs = sum(indivs, na.rm = T)) %>%
  spread(key = date, value = indivs)
```

Comment: Quite the solution, @Jakub.Novotny. This is fantastic and I'm really excited to see a solution that's so different than what I wrote myself. I definitely have a bit to learn!

Comment: Happy to help @Matt !

Answer (score 1):

Both @akrun and @Jakub.Novotny provided answers to my question. akrun provided an answer in the context of the code I wrote while Jakub.Novotny provided an entirely new solution.